# Sorting an array of doubles or CLLocationDistance values on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, arrays

I'm trying to sort a list of `CLLocationDistance` values by closest distance (ascending order). I first converted the values to `NSString` objects so that I could use the following sort:

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [distances sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

NSString cannot sort on the numeric value.

How can I set a list of numeric values in ascending order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you want is `sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:` using something like this:

```
NSInteger intSort(id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
    int v1 = [num1 intValue];
    int v2 = [num2 intValue];
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}

// sort things
NSArray *sortedArray; sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:intSort context:NULL];
```

[apple docs reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:)

Comment: should probably be using the blocks version now-a-days

Comment: How would you do it in swift?

Comment: @AndriusSteponavičius http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769107/sort-nsarray-with-sortedarrayusingcomparator

Answer (score 1):

Try using sortedArrayUsingSelector where you define the function to compare the elements heres a reference :http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingSelector:

Answer (score 0):

When you convert the values to strings the sort will be lexicographical instead of numerical, which is not what you want according your question. `CLLocationDistance` is defined to be type `double` according to the Apple docs. Given that, create your `NSArray` with `NSNumber` instances initialized with your `CLLocationDistance` data (see [`numberWithDouble`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithDouble:)), and use `NSArray`'s sorting implementation against those.

More on NSNumber is [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).