# function example for sortedArrayUsingFunction in Cocoa

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to create a compare function like the example on the apple site:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray%5FClass/NSArray.html#//apple%5Fref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingFunction%3Acontext%3A

The example is not objective-c.  Does anyone know how I can convert the example:

```
NSInteger intSort(id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
int v1 = [num1 intValue];
int v2 = [num2 intValue];
if (v1 < v2)
    return NSOrderedAscending;
else if (v1 > v2)
    return NSOrderedDescending;
else
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

to a function I can call with sortedArrayUsingFunction.

Thanks!

Comment: This example is most definitely Objective-C (it uses Objective-C message passing in the first two lines, as well as the id type in the calling isgnature). And it works for the use you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function works with `sortedArrayUsingFunction`, see [my updated answer on your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422840/sorting-an-array-of-doubles-or-cllocationdistance-values-on-the-iphone/1422881#1422881) for how to call it