# Sorting an Array error?

Tags: iphone, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array, from a previous post I was pointed to an answer in this thread, [Sorting an array of doubles or CLLocationDistance values on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422840/sorting-an-array-of-doubles-or-cllocationdistance-values-on-the-iphone/1422881#1422881)

Based of this my code is as follows:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [listArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:intSort context:nil];


NSInteger intSort(id num1, id num2, void *dummy)
{
    int v1 = [[num1 objectForKey:@"waypoint_order"] intValue];
    int v2 = [[num2 objectForKey:@"waypoint_order"] intValue];

    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

But its crashing on line int v1 = [[num1 objectForKey:@"waypoint_order"] intValue]; with 'objc_exception_throw'.

What am I doing wrong, I must be leaving out some functionality.

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: array out of bounds exception?

Comment: -[NSManagedObject objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a601f0.

Comment: Okay, I've just run a quick test and looped through my array output the contents of waypoint_order to the console.  Details are displayed so not sure how its getting out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are NSManagedObjects, you want valueForKey:, not objectForKey:

Like this...

int v1 = [[num1 valueForKey:@"waypoint_order"] intValue];

Hope that helps.

Comment: Firoze, thanks very much for this, I can't believe I missed it. I should have known that. I've been working a lot with NSManagedObjects lately.

Answer (score 1):

1. check num1 dictionary. is it autorelease or u release it somewhere in program.
2. or check value return by Dictionary may be it returning nil;
3. see linkArray object .at the time of creating u assigned last Value to nil or not .
   eg:`[[NSArray alloc]initWithObject:object1,object2,object3,nil];`

Comment: (1) Definitely not auto released and I'm not releasing it anywhere. (2) How do I do this ? (3) listArray is created from a NSFetchRequest and definitely no 'nil' value at the end.

Comment: Anybody any thoughts on this, I'm still having trouble.