# Displaying Records in Ascending order - Logic issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, cocoa-touch

I have a JSON string as the following;

```
{
    "1": {
        "name": "Jerry",
        "age": "12"

    },
    "2": {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": "16"

    "3": {.....
}
```

I have shown only 2 records but there will be a 100 of records in this JSON. There is an order in this 1,2,3 etc is the order number of the records.

I am ordering these records (as in displaying the 1st record, and then 2nd and 3rd and so forth). My code is provided below.

There is a problem here, when ever i have more than 10 records it doesn't display records in assending order. It first shows 1 and then 11,12,13... up to 19. Then it shows 2 and then 21,22,23 .... unto 29.

My code is as follows, how can i modify it to solve my issue ?

possible solution : if we could add a leading 0 in from of the numbers that are less than 10, it should filter out correctly. But i know that this is not the correct approach.

```
NSDictionary *dic = content;

            self.mutArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            NSArray *array = [dic allKeys];
            NSArray * sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

            for (NSString *str in sortedArray)
            {
                NSDictionary *dic2 = [dic objectForKey:str];
                Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];            
                person.nameOfRestaurant=[dic2 objectForKey:@"name"];
                person.personStartDate=[dic2 objectForKey:@"age"];

                [self.mutArr addObject:person];

            }

            self.personEntries = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.mutArr];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are sorting numbers *lexicographically* (i.e. as if they were *words*). You should provide your own implementation of the sort comparer that converts strings to integers, and only then compares them for ordering.

Comment: Are there any tutorial/sample code that explains how to do this ?

Comment: @user1315906 The answer at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1422881/335858) provides a working example of doing what you are trying to do.