# Sort NSArray with sortedArrayUsingComparator

Tags: sorting, swift, nsarray

In `Objective-C` I can sort an `NSArray` using this statement:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [persons sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Person *p1, Person *p2) {
    return [p1.name compare:p2.name];
}];
```

I'm unable to reproduce the same statement with **Swift**. All I found was using `Array`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can either use [Swift's built in sort functions](http://web.archive.org/web/20140603061027/https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Algorithms.html) or, since a Swift array is bridged to `NSArray` you can call `sortedArrayUsingComparator` from swift directly.

Using Swift's `sorted` function:

```
var sortedArray = sorted(persons) {
    (obj1, obj2) in

    // The downcast to Person is only needed if persons is an NSArray or a Swift Array of AnyObjects
    let p1 = obj1 as Person
    let p2 = obj2 as Person
    return p1.name < p2.name
}
```

Or, using `NSArray`'s `sortedArrayUsingComparator`:

```
var sortedArray = persons.sortedArrayUsingComparator {
    (obj1, obj2) -> NSComparisonResult in

    let p1 = obj1 as Person
    let p2 = obj2 as Person
    let result = p1.name.compare(p2.name)
    return result
}
```

Comment: `NSComparisonResult`  is now `ComparisonResult`.

Answer (score 16):

There's no need to avoid Swift `Array`.

It's bridged in both directions with `NSArray`, so for more type-safe code it's best to do your work with Swift arrays and bridge only when needed for interoperating with ObjC APIs. (And in most imported APIs, Swift automatically converts `NSArray` to `[AnyObject]`, so you don't even need to bridge very often.)

Assuming the `persons` array is an `[AnyObject]` you got from other API, you can cut down on the amount of type casting relative to other answers by casting the array first:

```
let sortedPersons = sorted(persons as [Person]) { $0.name < $1.name }
// sortedPersons has inferred type [Person]
```

Also, since you're using a comparator block only to sort on a specific property of your `Person` class, you might do better to use sort descriptors:

```
let sortedPersons = (persons as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([
    NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
])
```

(The `persons as NSArray` part may not be necessary if `persons` came from an ObjC API.)

Depending on how the `Person` class is implemented, sorting with descriptors can produce a more efficient sort on the backend. For example, if it's a Core Data managed object, sorting with descriptors might produce a SQL query that executes fast in the database and uses little memory, while sorting with a comparator closure requires instantiating every object from the database just to evaluate the closure against each.

Answer (score 9):

So try just write the same with Swift:

```
var sortedArray:NSArray = 
persons.sortedArrayUsingComparator(){(p1:AnyObject!, p2:AnyObject!) -> NSComparisonResult in

    if (p1 as Person).name > (p2 as Person).name {
       return NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
    }
    if (p1 as Person).name < (p2 as Person).name {
        return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }
    return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
 }
```

---

*Test (Playground):*

```
class Person{
  var name:String?
}

var p1:Person = Person()
p1.name = "a"    

var p3:Person = Person()
p3.name = "c"

var p2:Person = Person()
p2.name = "b"

var persons:NSArray = [p1,p3,p2]

var sortedArray:NSArray = persons.sortedArrayUsingComparator(){

    (p1:AnyObject!, p2:AnyObject!) -> NSComparisonResult in

    if (p1 as Person).name > (p2 as Person).name {
       return NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
    }
    if (p1 as Person).name < (p2 as Person).name {
        return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }
    return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }

for item:AnyObject in sortedArray{
    println((item as Person).name)
}
```

Output:

```
Optional("a")
Optional("b")
Optional("c")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift you can use new approach. Try to use sorted method instead sortedArrayUsingComparator like this...

```
var sortedArray = results.sorted {
    (obj1, obj2) -> Bool in 
    return obj1.count! > obj2.count!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you have custom object and want to sort by date

```
let sortedArray = self.posts.sorted {
            (obj1, obj2) -> Bool in
            return (obj1 as! PostModel).orderCancellionDate.compare( (obj2 as! PostModel).orderCancellionDate) == .orderedDescending
        }
```