# How can I start-over for loop?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop

I need to sort my post array, so that it will be arranged by its date. I think a solution is by looping trough the array and reorder it by creating new array that contain the post. So here is my code:

```
let newPostArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for post in postArray{

        print("sini3")

        let postDict = post as? NSDictionary

        if postDict!["timeAgo"]?.rangeOfString("d") != nil{

            newPostArray.addObject(post)
            //here is the problem

        }else if postDict!["timeAgo"]?.rangeOfString("w") != nil{

            newPostArray.addObject(post)

        }else if postDict!["timeAgo"]?.rangeOfString("m") != nil{

            newPostArray.addObject(post)

        }else{

            newPostArray.addObject(post)

        }

        print("jeng jeng \(newPostArray)")
    }
```

My logic is, after `newPostArray.addObject(post)` the loop continue to the next index and observe the second post and so on. How can I do that? Or is there any way I can reorder the array?

Comment: You can use `sortedArrayUsingComparator:`

Comment: @Larme can it be use on array of dictionary?

Comment: Yes. You can use a custom comparator for your custom object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769107/sort-nsarray-with-sortedarrayusingcomparator But it would always be better to keep a reference to a `NSDate` an not a `NSString` with "timeAgo". Much simpler, and a `NSSortDescriptor` should be enough.

Comment: You can use `break` to end execution of a loop or `continue` to go to the next iteration of the loop. However I would advise you use one of swift's built in sorts.

Comment: Do you have to use NSMutableArray? If you can use a Swift array, you can use the built-in `sort` or `sortInPlace` methods rather than writing your own sorting algorithm.